# declaration of an std_logic_vector having a variable size in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

In a **structural** description using the vhdl language, I want to decalare an std_logic_vector having a variable size. This size is determined by another component in the **same** structure. How Can I proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `package` with a `constant` assigned to the desired length, and use this `constant` when declaring the port length on the `component` and the `std_logic_vector` in the structural code.  This way the length will automatically match.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `generic`. Generic parameters are specified outside of the entity declaration. They are also well supported by simulators and synthesizers.

Comment: If the value is configurable, then a generic is the right choice, but if the value is fixed (non configurable), then the value should be specified in a single place.